# MongoConnectionException - Failed to connect to: localhost:27017

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I used the following PHP code to connect to MongoDB:

```
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Unknown error'

I tried lot of connection string possibilities that are posted in various blogs; nothing helps. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: sounds like a resolution problem. Try making a `MongoClient` with no connection string, also make sure you have mongodb running and can access it and there is no port block and also make sure that `localhost` is registered if you are using that.

Comment: seems like mongodb is not running

Comment: As a sanity check, try the ``mongo`` shell tool, eg. ``mongo --host localhost:27017``

Comment: thanks for all of your comments. the real problem is McAfee firewall. After i 'Turn Off' my firewall it is started working good.

Comment: This question shouldn't be locked !. This is the problem with stackoverflow "sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock" 
"sudo service mongod restart"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anybody has this issue, refer the following links first.

[Connection String URI Format](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-uri-format)

[PHP MongoClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php)

In my case McAfee firewall leads to this problem. When i 'Turn-Off' firewall it started working..