# PHP MongoDB Error -OpenShift

Tags: php, mongodb, exception, connection, openshift

Edit: I'm trying to connect via OpenShift.

Edit 2:
I've tried using "$con = new MongoClient();" with and without the $_ENV. Both return the same error.

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB using a PHP page (No CodeIgniter), and I keep getting this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message
>   'Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Network is unreachable

And well, here is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$ar = file_get_contents('php://input');
$ar = json_decode($ar);
$con = new Mongo($_ENV["OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL"]);
echo json_encode($ar); 
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoConnectionException - Failed to connect to: localhost:27017](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215833/mongoconnectionexception-failed-to-connect-to-localhost27017)

Comment: This should help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215833/mongoconnectionexception-failed-to-connect-to-localhost27017

Comment: Unfortunately, this is on OpenShift. I have no control over any firewall.

Comment: Is MongoDB installed and running on the server?

Comment: Yes. I had printed the version earlier, and if I remember correctly, it said 1.4.5

Either way, it definitely printed a version number.

Comment: `$_ENV` is not the correct way to read the `OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL` environment variable use `getenv('OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL');` in stead.